# How to show the convexity of this function?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $f,g:\mathbb{R}\supset I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$f(x)=x^r,\quad g(x)=x^{1/s}\quad 0<s\leq r<\infty. $$
How to show that $f\circ g:\mathbb{R}\supset I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a convex function ?

P.S. I've seen this in some paper I reviewed, where the author has mentioned it convex. But I couldn't prove that.

Comment: $f\circ g(x)=x^{r/s}$ is convex for $x\ge 0$, as can be seen by differentiating twice. However, for negative $x$ this is not true - consider $r=7,s=3$. Is there any restriction on $I$ which puts it inside $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$?

Comment: yes its for $x>0$.

Comment: But can we show it by definition? (In terms of $\lambda$ and $1-\lambda$).

Comment: Yes I tried  it in the same way at first but couldn't get enough argument to show that $$g(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y)=(\lambda x+(1-\lambda )y)^{1/s}\leq \lambda x^{1/s}+(1-\lambda )y^{1/s}.$$

Comment: Sorry, that was nonsense. $g$ is obviously not convex.

Comment: So the only possible way is to differentiate it twice?